# Wordpress Absolute Path

Tags: php, wordpress

Well, i am trying to access the WordPress pages that are saved in the localhost so i can study how the code works, i can access he main page of the site but when i try to access anything else it directs me to the online page of the webpage, not the localhost archive.

So i started looking at the files i have and i found this in wp-settings.php:

```
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-walker.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-ajax-response.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/capabilities.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/query.php' );
```

Someone told me it was because wordpress uses something called absolute path or something like that. Is there any way to remove that so i can cess the pages locally?

Sorry for bad english and if my question is stupid.

Comment: ABSPATH is defined based on the actual location the files are stored in (dirname(__FILE__) if memory serves).  So you shouldn't need to do anything providing you've placed wordpress in a local server.

Comment: for some reason it conects the page page on the internet and they saved the archives in the local host(at least that's what they told me they did here).

Comment: Ah, what you're trying to do is to use relative paths in the THEME, the above code is correct.  Basically WP's internal functions uses absolute paths in for all URLs.  Have a look at: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2012/06/relative-urls.html and Google - it's actually quite a lot of work to sort.  You could just change the URL of the site within the admin however to use localhost ;)

Comment: Well im trying to view the pages without conecting to wordpress so i can learn how they did some stuff in the codes(php, css and etc), i'll give it a look.

Answer (score 1):

They are defined as follows:
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(dirname(**FILE**)) . '/' );
define( 'WPINC', 'wp-includes' );

dirname is a PHP function that returns the path of the parent directory, and wp-includes is pretty self explanatory.

I would say ABSPATH is better because it's one of the first things WP loads and it also looks better:) But there is no real "right way" because they both work.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your local database. 
Go to the wp_options table look for the options `site_url` and `home`.
Change these accordingly, to your local URL.